# stuck on how to do a specific query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have three tables, items, values, and properties, their structure....

Items

- id
- title
- desc
- timestamp

Values

- id
- value
- itemID
- propID

Properties

- id
- name
- desc
- timestamp

Essentially, with this structure I can create an item, and then assign it any property or value. But I'm running into an issue of how I can search for existing items based on properties and values.

Such that, if I had an item, with a composite key dumped into this, if it were a normal table, I could so "SELECT * FROM items WHERE key1 = 'val1' AND key2 = 'val2'", but I can't figure out how to emulate a search like that, with this kind of structure. Does anyone else have any ideas?

This is for a system I was thrown into, so changing the layout of the tables may not be something I'll be given permission to do.

EDIT: I could break this into multiple steps, but the solutions I'm currently looking at will be slow and could becoming somewhat memory intensive, given the size of these data collections.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `INNER JOIN` query

```
SELECT *
FROM Items a
INNER JOIN Values b
ON a.id = b.itemID
INNER JOIN Propeties c
ON b.propID = c.id
WHERE c.title = 'height' AND b.value = '55'
```

Now in where you can place any of your column table, they are all joine now, just remember to preoend table alias (a,b,c) to your column name according

Comment: I'm getting stuck with the WHERE though, because I'd want to say, in that set of data, find all items that have the properties of height and width, for example, and have values of 55 and 120 respectively. I'm not sure how I'd structure that. I could pull items with a property.title = 'height' AND value.value = '55, but I'm not sure how to make it so that it has BOTH a property name of height, and a property name of width

Comment: That's as far as I can get, because I'd need to check for height and width having specific values. Currently, I'm thinking I'll need to put in sub queries, and instead of a WHERE statement, I think I'll need to have a HAVING statement, though that's not going to make things very efficient

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid joins you can create another table which will have three columns Item_Id, Property_Id and Value_Id. In this table you can search any thing on the basis of Id.

OR

You can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE IN (SELECT itemID FROM Values WHERE value=SOMEVALUE)
```

Comment: I'm considering creating a View at this point, but the reason this table layout was created was because it needed something that could handle lots of data in a universal way, when the data structure isn't always so defined. Instead of creating a new table for every oen set, we wanted something more universal so that we could fill in a few extra settings in a wizard, but apply some cool data sorts to it on a more universal level

Comment: @JohnSly I ve modified my answer. Look at it, is this you want?